# How can I change the column names of a chunk of columns?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, matrix

I have the following example table and would like to change the column names of e,f,g,h,i. In this example, let's say I just want to paste a "2" onto the end (so e2, f2, etc.) Is there a way to do this simply without a for loop?

```
m <- matrix(seq_len(12*5), nrow=5, ncol=12)
m <- data.frame(m)
names(m) <- letters[1:12]
m

  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
1 1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46 51 56
2 2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47 52 57
3 3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48 53 58
4 4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49 54 59
5 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60
```

After diligent searching, and trial/error I have not found the answer.

Comment: `names(m)[5:9] <- sprintf("%s2", names(m)[5:9])` should work

Comment: or if you want to avoid the format specifier, `names(m)[5:9] <- paste0( names(m)[5:9],"2" )`

Comment: These are answers. Why are they in the comments section? :p

Answer (score 1):

Both `sprintf` and `paste0` will work.  If the two who posted good answers in the comments wish to post answers, I'll remove this since they should get the credit.

Here's a `paste0` answer.

```
> names(m)[5:9] <- paste0(names(m[5:9]), 2)
> m
  a  b  c  d e2 f2 g2 h2 i2  j  k  l
1 1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46 51 56
2 2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47 52 57
3 3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48 53 58
4 4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49 54 59
5 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60
```